# How do I find a linear function using linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose L is a linear transformation in ℝ<sup>3</sup> → ℝ<sup>3</sup>. So here's what I know. I know that the basis (B) is $B = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$. I know that the coordinates of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\4\end{bmatrix}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and that the B matrix of L is $\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\-1&0&2\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. I also know that L(1, 0, 1) = (1, 2, 4) and L(1, -1, 0) = (0, 1, 2) and

L(0, 1, 2) = (2, -2, 0). So using that information, how would I find out what L(1, 2, 4) is?

I know that the answer is $\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\6\end{bmatrix}$ but I have no idea how to get to that answer.

Comment: Hint:  solve $(1,2,4)=A(1,0,1)+B(1,-1,0)+C(0,1,2)$ for $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that:
\begin{equation}
(1,2,4)=2(1,0,1)-1(1,-1,0)+1(0,1,2)
\end{equation}

so

\begin{equation}
L(1,2,4)=L[2(1,0,1)-1(1,-1,0)+1(0,1,2)]=\\=2L(1,0,1)-1L(1,-1,0)+1L(0,1,2)=\\=2(1,2,4)-(0,1,2)+(2,-2,0)=(4,1,6)
\end{equation}

where I used the linearity.